# Why is the surreal number collection not a set

Tags: set-theory, surreal-numbers

I am currently writing an essay on the surreal numbers, to finalise said essay I want to talk about how the surreals are 'too big' (or so ive heard) to be a set. Is there a concrete way of showing this. I did find that if $N:=\{S|\}$ where S is the set of all surreal numbers, it can be shown that $N\ngeq{N}$. Is this valid/enough to conclude the Surreals cannot be a set?

Comment: A surreal number $x$ is defined as such $x:=\{L|R\}$ where $L$ and $R$ are surreal numbers (or sets of surreal numbers) themselves. So if we assume the set of surreal numbers is S then it does not satisfy $N\ngeq{N}$. I should also note if $x=\{L|\}$ this simply means $R=\emptyset$ or $x=\{L|\emptyset\}$

Comment: the collection of surreal numbers contains all the ordinals, so if the collection of surreal numbers is a set, then also the collection of ordinals is a set, which is false

Comment: Thank you, is there a way of showing this without knowledge of ordinals?

Comment: you don't need the whole theory of ordinals, just the definition to build the Burali-Forti paradox, so it's not that "expensive" to do it this way

Comment: Your argument is valid, if the class $S$ of surreal numbers were a set, then the surreal number $\{S|\}$ would strictly larger than any surreal number, hence strictly larger than itself, which is definitely a contradiction.

Comment: @nombre or kam, it would be helpful if one of you could post an answer so this question no longer appears unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your proof is correct. If there is a set $S$ containing all surreal numbers, then there is a number $N:=\{S \ | \ \varnothing\}$ which is strictly greater than all elements of $S$, i.e. all numbers. In particular $N>N$: a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

One way to show that No (the Surreal numbers) is not a set, is to break it into smaller steps, that are relatively easy to demonstrate:

1. Show that On (the Ordinal numbers) are contained in No.
2. Prove that On is not a set (that is, a proper class).
3. Observe that that any superclass of a proper class, must itself be proper.

I am pretty sure that each of the above three have easily searchable links on them, in the event you'd like to see more details.  (As these are listed in decreasing order of difficulty, I suspect only #1 would be necessary to satisfy.)